# What is a graph that contains subdivision but not minors and vice versa?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

I am looking for graphs which satisfy the following conditions. (I have tried finding some possible solutions but no way to confirm them)

(a). a K5 as a minor but no K5-subdivision?
ans. Petersen Graph?

(b) a K3,3 as minor but no K3,3-subdivision?
ans. Toroidal Graph?

(c) a K5-subdivision but no K5 as minor?

(d) a K3,3-subdivision but no K3,3 as minor?

Comment: Suppose a graph does have a $K_5$-subdivision (often also called *topological minors* in other literature).  What does that mean about the graph?  That means that you can retract edges and delete vertices in such a way that you can form a $K_5$.  What does it mean to be a minor?  If you could form a $K_5$ using the previous set of moves to show its a *topological minor*, can you use that same set of moves to show it is a minor?

Comment: No. Topological minors are to be considered separate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be straight forward to prove the following statement:

> Let $G$ be a graph.  All induced subgraphs of $G$ are subgraphs of $G$.  All subgraphs of $G$ are topological minors of $G$.  All topological minors of $G$ are minors of $G$.

The other direction is not true.  As you mention in your post, there exists examples of minors which are not topological minors (e.g. the Peterson graph with minor $K_5$).

To see why this is true, remember the definitions of what it means to be each:

> A graph $H$ is an **induced subgraph** of a graph $G$ if there is a sequence of vertex removals that transforms $G$ into $H$.
>
> A graph $H$ is a **subgraph** of a graph $G$ if there is a sequence of vertex removals and/or edge removals that transforms $G$ into $H$.
>
> A graph $H$ is a **topological minor** of a graph $G$ if there is a sequence of vertex removals, edge removals, and/or suppression of vertices of degree 2 that transforms $G$ into $H$.
>
> A graph $H$ is a **minor** of a graph $G$ if there is a sequence of vertex removals, edge removals, suppression of vertices of degree 2, and/or edge contractions that transforms $G$ into $H$.
>
> These sequences are allowed to be of length zero, implying that a graph is always an induced subgraph, subgraph, topological minor, and minor of itself.

If you know something is, for example, a subgraph of $G$, then there is some sequence of transformations from a list of allowable transformations.  Since each of those transformations are allowable for, say, showing it is a minor, the same sequence of transformations can be used to show that it is a minor.

Comment: Of course, "suppression of a degree-2 vertex" is just a special case of "edge contraction", so it is usually not listed explicitly in the definition of a minor.

Comment: Hi Guys,
I am a noob in this study. So could you please examples for the questions I asked?

Comment: @DhirajEadara as the proof above indicates, no we cannot provide examples for (c) and (d) because they don't exist.  All topological minors are also minors.  There are no minors that are not topological minors.  I.e. If a graph has a $K_5$ subdivision, then it necessarily has a $K_5$ minor.  If a graph does not have a $K_5$ minor, then it cannot have a $K_5$ subdivision.  You already have examples listed for (a) and (b).